# Understanding あったもの

Tags: grammar

> それを知りつつ、シンは口を開く。
>
> 「一応、中佐からは抜けてもいいとは言われてるけど」
>
> 「冗談でしょ。ここで逃げたら白ブタと一緒じゃん」
>
> 吐き捨てて、それからセオはふっと笑った。
>
> 「……って、シンだって中佐に啖呵きってきたんでしょ。僕達もそれは一緒だから」
>
> 作戦要旨説明の間中、グレーテはシンと目を合わせなかった。少年兵の犠牲を厭うグレーテのこと、ブリーフィング前に一悶着あった**もの**とはそれで察したらしい。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉 安里アサト

How should I understand the bold もの? It seems unnecessary here because the sentence still works without the もの.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are right that もの can be dropped in the sentence.

It may be called redundant but should be very common, e.g. in a construction like ～ものと思われます instead of ～と思われます.

[The following meaning](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE/#jn-219726) is the relevant one.

> ５ 他の語句を受けて、その語句の内容を体言化する形式名詞。
>
> ㋐判断などを強調して示す。「負けたのがよほどくやしかった―と見える」「何をされるかわかった―じゃない」

Comment: Thank you. I get it. And could you look at the もの (in ものらしい) in this example? Is this もの the same usage as that in op? Namely, an emphasis of some judgment?

Comment: 航空兵器、誘導兵器は封殺され、同等の超長距離砲も持たないのであれば、全軍上げての突撃作戦に賭けるより他に術はない。目先の戦死者数の少ない作戦に固執して戦線の端からレールガンに焼かれる結末を、三国軍は選ばなかったものらしい。

Comment: @chinoalpha Yes. Just as a side note, it sounds more natural that way, rather than really emphasizing.